# Force logout specific user in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-breeze

Hi I know there is answer to this questions on forum but they are outdated and they aren't working on laravel 10. I'm using laravel 10 and laravel breeze and I must force logout of this user

```
$user = User::find($userid);
```

I was thinking about using code like this

```
/**
 * Destroy an authenticated session.
 */
public function destroy(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

from AuthenticatedSessionController

But i don't know how to edit this code to work in my code

Comment: “i know there is answer to this questions on forum” - to be clear, is the posted text from said forum, or something else?

Comment: Why not look to the Laravel 10 [logout](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#logging-out) documentation? ... where they have example usage too.